# Python web scraper "find_all(attr)" returning empty list

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I'm scraping a website and I basically want to store some table data in a dictionary.

Following is my program to scrape-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import defaultdict
import json
import requests
import re 


sauce = 'http://m.ironman.com/triathlon/events/americas/ironman/world-championship/results.aspx'


r = requests.get(sauce)
data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

def parse_table(soup):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    my_table = soup.find('tbody')

    for row in my_table.find_all('tr'):
        try:
            name, div_rank, gender_rank, overall_rank, swim, bike, run,
            total_time = (col.text.strip() for col in row.find_all('td')[2:])
        except ValueError:
            continue

        result[name].append({
            'div_rank': div_rank,
            'gender_rank': gender_rank,
            'overall_rank': overall_rank,
            'swim': swim,
            'bike': bike,
            'run': run,
            'total_time': total_time
            })

    return result


print(json.dumps(parse_table(soup), indent=3))
```

I checked that `print(my_table)` is not empty but if I check `print(my_table.find_all('tr'))`, it is empty. All the data I need is inside the `td` tag which is inside the `tr` tags which are inside the `my_table`.

Why is `find_all('tr')` returning empty?

---

Edit: The output of `print(my_table)` is basically a bunch of `tr`s like-

```
<tr data-bib-number="838"
                    data-result-page="?bidid=838&rd=10/13/2018 12:00:00 AM&race=worldchampionship"
                    data-gender="female"
                    data-age="50-54"
                    data-country="usa">
                    <td><span class="icon-flag USA" style="background-image: url(/Media/mvc/Images/Countries/usa.svg );"></span></td>
                    <td class="text-bold text-left">Younts, Joanna <span class="bib-number hidden">838</span></td>
                    <td data-order="133813">                                                                          <span class="last-position"></span></td>
                    <td data-order="011952" class="small-hidden">01:19:52</td>
                    <td data-order="055020" class="small-hidden">05:50:20</td>
                    <td data-order="061111" class="small-hidden">06:11:11</td>
                    <td data-order="58" class="small-hidden group-rank">58</td>
                    <td data-order="523" class="small-hidden gender-rank">523</td>
                    <td data-order="2008" class="overall-rank">2008</td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: What is the output you get for `print(my_table)`?

Comment: @BKS Just added it.

Comment: Could you be getting a `ValueError` exception for _every_ row, thus you're never adding anything to `results`?  Try adding a print statement before the `continue`, just to see how often it happens.

Comment: Also, the two lines in the `try` block are obviously meant to be a continuation, but they're not formatted correctly to actually be a valid continuation.  Can you doublecheck that part?

Comment: Tried both your suggestions, didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the actual return HTML in the table contains a comment, not rows (maybe to frustrate scrapers?). Outside of that, there were multiple Python errors as well.  If we capture the `tbody` and then extract the comment from it (which contains the real data), we can then parse the comment as an HTML table.

The rows are not ordered like they appear when viewing the HTML in a browser, I imagine they are shuffled once they are converted from a comment. Anyways, we then access the data as they are organized in our source which is different than it is displayed in the browser. Total time does not seem to be contained in the table, I imagine the JavaScript code that converts the comment into a table calculates that, so you may have to calculate that yourself (I will not be doing that here).

Code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
from collections import defaultdict
import json
import requests

sauce = 'http://m.ironman.com/triathlon/events/americas/ironman/world-championship/results.aspx'


r = requests.get(sauce)
data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

def parse_table(soup):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    my_table = soup.find('tbody')

    for node in my_table.children:
        if isinstance(node, Comment):
            # Get content and strip comment "<!--" and "-->"
            # Wrap the rows in "table" tags as well.
            data = '<table>{}</table>'.format(node[4:-3])
            break

    table = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        name, _, swim, bike, run, div_rank, gender_rank, overall_rank = [col.text.strip() for col in row.find_all('td')[1:]]

        result[name].append({
            'div_rank': div_rank,
            'gender_rank': gender_rank,
            'overall_rank': overall_rank,
            'swim': swim,
            'bike': bike,
            'run': run,
            # 'total_time': total_time
        })

    return result

print(json.dumps(parse_table(soup), indent=3))
```

Which will get you various entries (I will just show a couple):

```
{
   "Goodlad, Martin 977": [
      {
         "div_rank": "156",
         "gender_rank": "899",
         "overall_rank": "1026",
         "swim": "00:57:56",
         "bike": "05:00:29",
         "run": "04:20:04"
      }
   ],
   "Maley, Joel 1840": [
      {
         "div_rank": "39",
         "gender_rank": "171",
         "overall_rank": "186",
         "swim": "01:12:01",
         "bike": "04:34:59",
         "run": "03:17:13"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Great catch on the comment thing! However, when I run the new edits, I'm facing an error on the `if isinstance` line- `NameError: name 'Comment' is not defined`

Comment: Does that mean my original edit worked, and the new one doesn't?  If you forget to import Comment from bs4, you would get that error.  I'd make sure you are importing that type from bs4. Maybe you just copied part of my solution?

Comment: Oh, my bad I forgot to import Comment from bs4. Btw, this scraper takes care of all the pages on that website, right? Or do we need to write a separate function for navigating between different pages?

Comment: I honestly don't know, but it appears to output many more entries than what I see on the first page, so I assume it handles all of them, but I simply didn't look to close.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `html.parser`.

Can you install `lxml` and change the code to following:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
```

Output:

```
defaultdict( < class 'list' > , 
        {'1': [{'div_rank': '1', 'gender_rank': '1', 'overall_rank': '00:50:37', 'swim': '04:16:04', 'bike': '02:41:31', 'run': '07:52:39', 'total_time': '5000'}],
          '2': [{'div_rank': '2', 'gender_rank': '2', 'overall_rank': '00:54:07', 'swim': '04:12:25', 'bike': '02:45:41', 'run': '07:56:41', 'total_time': '4951'}],
          '3': [{'div_rank': '3', 'gender_rank': '3', 'overall_rank': '00:49:31', 'swim': '04:21:18', 'bike': '02:46:03', 'run': '08:01:09', 'total_time': '4898'}],
          '4': [{'div_rank': '4', 'gender_rank': '4', 'overall_rank': '00:47:45', 'swim': '04:18:45', 'bike': '02:52:33', 'run': '08:03:17', 'total_time': '4872'}],
          '5': [{'div_rank': '5', 'gender_rank': '5', 'overall_rank': '00:49:28', 'swim': '04:17:17', 'bike': '02:53:38', 'run': '08:04:41', 'total_time': '4855'}],
          '6': [{'div_rank': '6', 'gender_rank': '6', 'overall_rank': '00:54:02', 'swim': '04:12:58', 'bike': '02:52:56', 'run': '08:04:45', 'total_time': '4854'}],
          '7': [{'div_rank': '7', 'gender_rank': '7', 'overall_rank': '00:50:53', 'swim': '04:15:41', 'bike': '02:54:15', 'run': '08:05:54', 'total_time': '4841'}],
          '8': [{'div_rank': '8', 'gender_rank': '8', 'overall_rank': '00:49:33', 'swim': '04:18:51', 'bike': '02:56:27', 'run': '08:09:34', 'total_time': '4797'}],
          '9': [{'div_rank': '9', 'gender_rank': 'overall_rank': '00:50:51', 'swim': '04:09:06', 'bike': '03:06:18', 'run': '08:10:32', 'total_time': '4785'}],
          '10': [{'div_rank': '10', 'gender_rank': '10', 'overall_rank': '00:54:14', 'swim': '04:11:27', 'bike': '03:00:02', 'run': '08:11:04', 'total_time': '4779'}],
          '11': [{'div_rank': '11', 'gender_rank': '11', 'overall_rank': '00:47:46', 'swim': '04:19:44', 'bike': '02:59:24', 'run': '08:11:41', 'total_time': '4771'}],
          '12': [{'div_rank': '12', 'gender_rank': '12', 'overall_rank': '00:50:39', 'swim': '04:27:47', 'bike': '02:50:36', 'run': '08:13:47', 'total_time': '4746'}],
          '13': [{'div_rank': '13', 'gender_rank': '13', 'overall_rank': '00:50:56', 'swim': '04:15:17', 'bike': '03:02:50', 'run': '08:14:02', 'total_time': '4743'}],
          '14': [{'div_rank': '14', 'gender_rank': '14', 'overall_rank': '00:50:48', 'swim': '04:19:48', 'bike': '02:58:04', 'run': '08:14:31', 'total_time': '4737'}],
          '15': [{'div_rank': '15', 'gender_rank': '15', 'overall_rank': '00:50:39', 'swim': '04:19:58', 'bike': '03:00:17', 'run': '08:15:58', 'total_time': '4720'}],
          '16': [{'div_rank': '16', 'gender_rank': '16', 'overall_rank': '00:50:45', 'swim': '04:25:04', 'bike': '02:57:35', 'run': '08:17:54', 'total_time': '4697'}],
          '17': [{'div_rank': '17', 'gender_rank': '17', 'overall_rank': '00:50:41', 'swim': '04:21:02', 'bike': '03:02:00', 'run': '08:18:18', 'total_time': '4692'}],
          '18': [{'div_rank': '18', 'gender_rank': '18', 'overall_rank': '00:50:45', 'swim': '04:19:56', 'bike': '03:03:47', 'run': '08:19:13', 'total_time': '4681'}],
          '19': [{'div_rank': '19', 'gender_rank': '19', 'overall_rank': '00:47:43', 'swim': '04:19:01', 'bike': '03:08:42', 'run': '08:19:40', 'total_time': '4675'}],
          '20': [{'div_rank': '20', 'gender_rank': '20', 'overall_rank': '00:47:51', 'swim': '04:18:38', 'bike': '03:10:07', 'run': '08:21:52', 'total_time': '4649'}]})
```

Comment: That is weird. I wonder why it's working for you and not for me.

Comment: Did you check whether `lxml` is installed successfully

Comment: which OS are you using

Comment: can you try installing from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml)